# XML combine documents

Tags: groovy

I am working on Boomi interface and I need to combine individual xml documents in to single output documents . The standard combine document step is not working properly.

All xml documents are of same structure .

First Document

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="ETACIV">
      <CAMPO ID="ETA_ETCNOM" SEC=" " FECHA=" ">abc</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>
```

Second document

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="SADMIN ">
      <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/03/2015">01/03/2015</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>
```

Third document

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="SADMIN ">
      <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/06/2015">01/06/2015</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
     <SECCION ID="ETACIV">
     <CAMPO ID="ETA_ETCNOM" SEC=" " FECHA=" ">abc</CAMPO>
     </SECCION>
     <SECCION ID="SADMIN ">
     <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/03/2015">01/03/2015</CAMPO>
     <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/06/2015">01/06/2015</CAMPO>
     </SECCION>
   </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>
```

---

The merging on elements are the same as attributes ? Technically , I need all the documents to be merged on ID attribute of CAMPO .

Any help greatly appreciated .

Thanks
Nag

I tried the below code ; getting Premature end of file. error.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.xpath.XPath;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult;
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;


for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
  InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
  Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

def xs = new XmlSlurper()
def employee = xs.parse(is);
String Encod = "UTF-8" ;
HashMap<String, GPathResult> CampoMap = new HashMap<String, GPathResult>()

employee.EMPLEADOS.EMPLEADO.PROCESO.SECCION.CAMPO.each {
    CampoMap["${it.@ID}"] = it
}

new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
     mkp.xmlDeclaration(["version":"1.0", "encoding":"UTF-8"]);
    EMPLEADOS {
        EMPLEADO.PROCESO.SECCION.each {
            if (CampoMap["${it.@ID}"] != null) {
                it.appendNode(CampoMap["${it.@id}"].sites)
            }
            out << it
        }
    }
} .writeTo(is.newWriter(Encod))
}
  dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
```

The new code is

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def parser = new XmlParser()
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
  InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
  Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

def mergedDocument = (0..<dataContext.dataCount)
    .collect { XmlParser.parse(dataContext.getStream(it)) }
    .inject { nodeA, nodeB -> merge(nodeA, nodeB) }


builder.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version:'1.0', encoding:'UTF-8')
builder.EMPLEADOS {
    doc1.EMPLEADO.each { empleado ->
        EMPLEADO(empleado.attributes()) {
           empleado.PROCESO.each { proceso -> 
               PROCESO(proceso.attributes()) 
           }

           empleado.SECCION.each { seccion ->
               SECCION(seccion.attributes()) {
                   seccion.CAMPO.each { campo ->
                       CAMPO(campo.attributes(), campo.value().head())
                   }
               }
           }            
        }
    }
}
is = mergedDocument ;
}


/*
 * Category to simplify XML node comparisons.
 * Basically, two Nodes are equal if their attributes are the same.
 */
// class NodeCategory {
//    static boolean equals(Node me, Node other) {
//        me.attributes() == other.attributes()
//    }

//    static boolean isCase(List<Node> nodes, Node other) {
//      nodes.find { it == other } != null
//    }
//}

/*
 * Merges document b into document a.
 * WARNING: This method is destructive; it modifies document a
 * @Returns a, for convenience
 */
def merge(a, b) {
//    use(NodeCategory) {
        b.EMPLEADO.each { empleado ->
            def existingEmpleado = a.EMPLEADO.find { 
                it == empleado
            }

            if(existingEmpleado) {
                // Empleado already exists, must merge differences.

                // Add any missing PROCESO nodes.
                empleado.PROCESO
                   .findAll { !(it in existingEmpleado.PROCESO) }
                   .with {
                       delegate.each { existingEmpleado.append(it) }
                   }

                // Add any missing SECCION nodes.
                empleado.SECCION
                   .findAll { !(it in existingEmpleado.SECCION) }
                   .with {
                       delegate.each { existingEmpleado.append(it) }
                   }

                // Add any missing CAMPO nodes.
                empleado.SECCION.each { seccion ->
                    existingEmpleado.SECCION
                        .find { it == seccion }
                        .with {
                            seccion.CAMPO
                                .findAll { !(it in delegate.CAMPO) }
                                .each { delegate.append(it) }
                        }
                }
            } else {
                // Empleado does not exist, go ahead and add it as-is.
                a.append(empleado)
            }
        }    
 //   }

    return a
}
```

Comment: Please see above code

Answer (score 2):

First, I should mention that a generic method for *combining* XML documents is impossible because the merging process is contextual. How XML nodes are merged is dependent on what the nodes *mean*. A computer is incapable of figuring out the meaning on your data, so you as the programmer have to provide the instructions. Having said that, here's how to merge **YOUR** XML documents.

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def parser = new XmlParser()
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

def doc1 = parser.parseText('''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="ETACIV">
      <CAMPO ID="ETA_ETCNOM" SEC=" " FECHA=" ">abc</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO> 
</EMPLEADOS>''')

def doc2 = parser.parseText('''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="SADMIN ">
      <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/03/2015">01/03/2015</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>''')

def doc3 = parser.parseText('''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EMPLEADOS>
  <EMPLEADO TIPO="A" NUMERO="123">
    <PROCESO PERIODO="201603" TT="MN" PAC="9999" />
    <SECCION ID="SADMIN ">
      <CAMPO ID="SAD_SADESO" SEC=" " FECHA="01/06/2015">01/06/2015</CAMPO>
    </SECCION>
  </EMPLEADO>
</EMPLEADOS>''')


merge(doc1, doc2)
merge(doc1, doc3)

builder.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version:'1.0', encoding:'UTF-8')
builder.EMPLEADOS {
    doc1.EMPLEADO.each { empleado ->
        EMPLEADO(empleado.attributes()) {
           empleado.PROCESO.each { proceso -> 
               PROCESO(proceso.attributes()) 
           }

           empleado.SECCION.each { seccion ->
               SECCION(seccion.attributes()) {
                   seccion.CAMPO.each { campo ->
                       CAMPO(campo.attributes(), campo.value().head())
                   }
               }
           }            
        }
    }
}

println writer

/*
 * Category to simplify XML node comparisons.
 * Basically, two Nodes are equal if their attributes are the same.
 */
class NodeCategory {
    static boolean equals(Node me, Node other) {
        me.attributes() == other.attributes()
    }

    static boolean isCase(List<Node> nodes, Node other) {
        nodes.find { it == other } != null
    }
}

/*
 * Merges document b into document a.
 * WARNING: This method is destructive; it modifies document a
 * @Returns a, for convenience
 */
def merge(a, b) {
    use(NodeCategory) {
        b.EMPLEADO.each { empleado ->
            def existingEmpleado = a.EMPLEADO.find { 
                it == empleado
            }

            if(existingEmpleado) {
                // Empleado already exists, must merge differences.

                // Add any missing PROCESO nodes.
                empleado.PROCESO
                   .findAll { !(it in existingEmpleado.PROCESO) }
                   .with {
                       delegate.each { existingEmpleado.append(it) }
                   }

                // Add any missing SECCION nodes.
                empleado.SECCION
                   .findAll { !(it in existingEmpleado.SECCION) }
                   .with {
                       delegate.each { existingEmpleado.append(it) }
                   }

                // Add any missing CAMPO nodes.
                empleado.SECCION.each { seccion ->
                    existingEmpleado.SECCION
                        .find { it == seccion }
                        .with {
                            seccion.CAMPO
                                .findAll { !(it in delegate.CAMPO) }
                                .each { delegate.append(it) }
                        }
                }
            } else {
                // Empleado does not exist, go ahead and add it as-is.
                a.append(empleado)
            }
        }    
    }

    return a
}
```

The process goes like this:

1. The `merge(Node a, Node b)` method traverses through the nodes, handling each case so that `a` ends up being the combination of both documents (node trees). It's based on figuring out whether a node in `b` is already in `a`. If not, the node is added as-is. Otherwise, merge the changes `a` accordingly. Yes, this method is butt ugly and was a real PITA to write. Please, for the sake of sound programming, refactor the beast.
2. Finally, a `MarkupDocumentBuilder` is used to process the final node tree and produce a serialized XML document.

You may notice there's a Groovy category involved. It's used to simplify the `Node` comparisons.

### Addendum - Using input streams

You can invoke the same process using `InputStream`s as the source of XML documents. It would go something like this:

```
def parser = new XmlParser()
def mergedDocument = (0..<dataContext.dataCount)
    .collect { parser.parse(dataContext.getStream(it) }
    .inject { nodeA, nodeB -> merge(nodeA, nodeB) }
```

Then, you can process `mergedDocument` with the `MarkupBuilder`.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel , Thank you so much for your inputs. Can we make this code without classes . I cannot define inner classes in boomi. Also, my documents are through input stream . In each iteration I should add the documents to the previous iteration document.

Comment: Yes, you can forgo the `NodeCategory` class. Note however, that it is not an inner class. In Groovy you can have multiple classes per file without using inner classes. To remove `NodeCategory` you'll need to replicate its logic where it's used in `merge()`. For instance, `equals()` is called when the equality operator is used (==) and `isCase()` is called when the `in` operator is used. Yes, you can use input streams. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Oh damn, that was my fault. I should have written `parser.parse(dataContext.getStream(it)`. XmlParser doesn't have a parser() static method: that's what the error is trying to say. Anyway, sure I can help you get it working. I have a Slack community you can join. It's called 'Grails Noob', but Groovy novices are welcome too. http://emmanuelrosa.com